# What is a good pattern for correctly appending to a file with async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it safe to call functions like `fs.appendFile()` repeatedly? A contrived example you could consider is when using `child_process.spawn` and a "for-async-of" loop to implement `tee` with js. We get file data in chunks, and would like to append them to a file and perform other processing. If the `appendFile()` is promisified and `await`ed, then the execution shall be paused until we know the file has been written, which might be wasted time. However, if I do not await this, I feel no longer certain that my potentially quickly repeated calls to `appendFile` could result in an interlaced output file.

Does the node `fs` library perform the file locking for me? What might be an effective way to do so? Should I write a helper class to offload the work into in its own asynchronous appending loop?

Here is my testing so far, which is encouraging though will seemingly never be conclusive:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node                                                             
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                   
const fs = require('fs');                                                       
const util = require('util');                                                   
const start = new Date();                                                       
const proc = spawn('seq 1 200000', { shell:true });                             
proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');                                                
(async()=>{                                                                     
    for await (const data of proc.stdout) {                                     
        console.log(new Date() - start, `got ${data.length} chars of stdout`);  
        util.promisify(fs.appendFile)('junk', data);                            
    };                                                                          
})();
```

Output:

```
5 'got 8192 chars of stdout'
7 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
7 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
7 'got 53248 chars of stdout'
8 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
8 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
8 'got 49152 chars of stdout'
9 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
9 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
9 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
9 'got 24576 chars of stdout'
9 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
9 'got 40960 chars of stdout'
10 'got 49152 chars of stdout'
10 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
10 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
10 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
10 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
10 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
11 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
11 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
11 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
11 'got 24576 chars of stdout'
11 'got 24576 chars of stdout'
11 'got 32768 chars of stdout'
12 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
12 'got 65536 chars of stdout'
13 'got 64191 chars of stdout'
```

`diff junk <(sort -n junk)` reveals that the output is correct (nothing got interlaced).

When I added `await` in front of the append call, the time taken to perform the write increased by a factor of about 30%.

I guess based on the results I will just await the appendFile call even though it looks safe to skip that. The performance hit is tiny.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this would be an issue, the calls & chunks will all be scheduled in the correct order, the OS takes care of the rest.

Comment: The is not a very efficient way to write a bunch of data to the end of a file.  You're opening and closing the file every time through your loop whereas you could open the file before the loop, close the file after the loop and just write to the file inside the loop.

Comment: Why don't you just pipe `proc.stdout` to your  file?  Open a writestream in append mode.  Then, pipe to it.  And, if you use streams, you don't have to worry about locking.  The stream will naturally write the bytes in the order received, all through the same file handle.  If the data arrives in small chunks, it will also be buffered within the stream for efficiency purposes.

Comment: The use case is a test framework in which process output streams will be streamed by this backend to a browser (in real time), as well as written to the file. This is more elegant than streaming to the file first and reading back from it. It's also possible that there would be multiple front-end subscribers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your code is theoretically subject to race conditions** because the various writes in different `fs.appendFile()` operations could clash and could be in flight at the same time because your `for` loop runs to completion before all the `fs.appendFile()` operations are done.  Therefore you will have multiple `fs.appendFile()` operations in flight at the same time.  **This is not a safe way to write code.**  If you want the writes serialized in a specific order and so that they cannot collide, you should guarantee that this happens by the way you write your code, not by the luck of how the timing all works out or how the internals of the library code are written.

I have proven in a test app that `fs.appendFile()` does **not** acquire exclusive access and **does not lock the file** and mulitple `fs.appendFile()` writes from the same program can overwrite one another or they can interleave in an unpredictable order.  This means that you are taking a risk by having multiple `fs.appendFile()` operations in flight at the same time.  My guess is that you are getting lucky because of the speed of your disk writes and the ability to handle large chunks at once.  If the underlying system had to break the writes up into multiple chunks you'd have more of a chance of conflict.

In addition, this luck probably also varies by OS, by file system type and by file system load and performance.

In fact, I've shown that even a simple loop like this where the data for each write is simply 40 rows of this:

```
'0123456789abcdefghijhklmopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\n'
```

And, this code:

```
const numIterations = 100;
for (let i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    fs.appendFile("output.txt", `(${i}):` + testData, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(i, err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    });
}
```

Won't write all the data in order.  I get the first four iterations of the loop written in this order:

```
(0), (2), (3), (1)
```

then, later there's

```
(10), (11), (9)
```

out of order.

---

If you use `for await (...)` and make the `for` loop wait just a tiny amount between iterations, the writes again go in order (no surprise).  But, I think this just goes to show that it's inherently a race condition, just sometimes you can create conditions where the race condition doesn't usually bite you.  That still isn't the right way to code it.

---

In addition, the promisify stuff in this code isn't doing anything useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node                                                             
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                   
const fs = require('fs');                                                       
const util = require('util');                                                   
const start = new Date();                                                       
const proc = spawn('seq 1 200000', { shell:true });                             
proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');                                                
(async()=>{                                                                     
    for await (const data of proc.stdout) {                                     
        console.log(new Date() - start, `got ${data.length} chars of stdout`);  
        util.promisify(fs.appendFile)('junk', data);                            
    };                                                                          
})();
```

This code may not be doing what you thought it was.  The `util.promisify(fs.appendFile)` does nothing useful there because you aren't waiting for the promise that it returns when you call it.  Therefore, it's no different at all from just calling `fs.appendfile()` except if you got an error, you would get a complaint about an unhandled rejection.

If you do `await` that promise, then it will make the code safe as the `await` will force the `for` loop to wait for one operation to finish before the next iteration starts.

---

Now, on to some of your questions?

> Does the node fs library perform the file locking for me?

No, it does not.  On Windows 10 (where I tested), I could cause data conflict when some other code in the same app was trying to write to the same file where data got overwritten.  I could also even get the same loop to be written out of order.

> What might be an effective way to do so?

My recommendation for a problem like this would be pipe the input to an output stream.  Open the stream once and pipe the input to it.  Skip the loop entirely.  Skip calling `fs.appendFile()` over and over which has to open the file, seek to the end, write data, then close the file, everytime through the loop.  Very inefficient.

> Should I write a helper class to offload the work into in its own asynchronous appending loop?

No, just use a stream.  A stream is built exactly for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node                                                             
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                   
const fs = require('fs');                                                       
const util = require('util');                                                   
const start = new Date();                                                       
const proc = spawn('seq 1 200000', { shell:true });                             
proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');                                                
let outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('junk');
proc.stdout.pipe(outputStream);
```

> What is a good pattern for correctly appending to a file with async await?

If you really want to use async/await here, then you can use await in front of the file operation.  That will make it safe because your force the loop to wait for the completion of one write before starting the next write.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node                                                             
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;                                   
const fs = require('fs');                                                       
const util = require('util');                                                   
const start = new Date();                                                       
const proc = spawn('seq 1 200000', { shell:true });                             
proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');                                                
(async()=>{                                                                     
    for await (const data of proc.stdout) {                                     
        console.log(new Date() - start, `got ${data.length} chars of stdout`);  
        await fs.promises.appendFile('junk', data);                            
    };                                                                          
})();
```

**Other Notes:**

You're using `for await ()` so you already have a recent version of node.js.  If you did want promisified file functions, you can just use the `fs.promises` interface that is built-in instead of manually promisifying `fs` functions.

Comment: "*I could cause data conflict when some other code was trying to write to the same file*" - I don't think that's what the question is about. Rather, is it possible that the consecutive but non-awaited `appendFile` calls collide with themselves or get written in a different order than the respective calls?

Comment: @Bergi - They theoretically can collide.  It isn't easy to reproduce it now in the same loop, but that doesn't mean it's safe.  There is nothing in the implementation of `fs.appendFile()` that makes the loop safe.  You're running multiple `fs.appendFile()` operations in parallel where each one consists of open, write, close.  I used another write just to prove that `fs.appendFile()` had no lock on the file and therefore wasn't safe from some other write, whether that was in the same loop or not.  The vulnerability could well vary by OS, by system load or even drive type/performance too.

Comment: @Bergi - The underlying conclusion here is that I proved that one `fs.appendFile()` is not safe from another `fs.appendFile()` (it doesn't lock the file) therefore you should program accordingly.  Do, you disagree with the conclusion?

Comment: Oh, you mean you used some other code in the same script, running in the same nodejs process? I somehow was thinking of "some other program". Thanks for the clarification. Makes sense now.

Comment: @Bergi -  Other `fs.appendFile()` calls in the same script.  I will clarify that in my answer.

Comment: @Bergi - Actually, I just found out that even a single loop by itself can mess up the order of the writes.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! as I wrote in my question, based on simple performance tests, I would be awaiting the call to eliminate the race condition. It's not ideal though because it turns it effectively into a synchronous call (although slightly less bad since it still "yields").

Comment: @StevenLu - You picked the wrong structure if you want the best performance.  Use a stream and then there's no waiting.  The stream buffers things in order and writes as fast as it can and isn't constantly opening and closing the file on every iteration through the loop.  If you use `.pipe()` everything is automatic including back pressure.  Your structure is about the worst possible performance.  Did my answer provide an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by **safe**, but there's nothing wrong with it as long as you don't need the file appended in a specified order. Judging by your question including `fs.appendFile` that probably **is** what you want.

Because you're dealing with Promises it's likely better to write a class or a Constructor so that you can serialize your Promises and do something when finished.

This is one that I had written a while back that may help you:

---

### Serial.js

```
function Serial(promises = []) {
    return {
        promises,
        resolved: [],
        addPromise: function(fn) {
            promises.push(fn);
        },
        resolve: async function(cb = i => i, err = (e) => console.log("trace: Serial.resolve " + e)) {
            try {
                for await (let p of this[Symbol.iterator]()) {}
                return this.resolved.map(cb);
            } catch (e) {
                err(e);
            }
        },
        [Symbol.iterator]: async function*() {
            this.resolved = [];
            for (let promise of this.promises) {
                let p = await promise().catch(e => console.log("trace: Serial[Symbol.iterator] ::" + e));
                this.resolved.push(p);
                yield p;
            }
        }
    }
}
module.exports = Serial;
```

---

### Index.js

```
const Serial = require("./js/Serial");
let application_complete = false;

    new Serial([
                 appendPromise1,
                 appendPromise2, 
                 appendPromise3
                        ])
                        .resolve()
                        .then(() => { 
                        application_complete = true;
                    });


process.on("beforeExit", async () => {
    await application_complete;
    console.log("File Appended!");
})
```

**Note** The `beforeExit` event is just to prevent the node environment from closing before the asynchronous function is returned. The Serial Constructor doesn't require it or anything.

---

Comment: This seems way, way overly complicated for the job at hand.  Just use a stream and let the stream take care of writing the data in order.  That's what the do.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think it's too complicated. This answer was added before a lot of information was edited into the question

Comment: It seems likely that if the promise is provided as a black box and I had some need to make sure that they run sequentially but asynchronously, this mechanism would work. However in practice for this problem the stream would be the approach with the better, clearer interface, and would run with less overhead: superior by every measure.